# Is it posible to cast to the receiver the input from the phone microphone?

Tags: ios, google-cast, chromecast

I would like to know if it is posible to cast the audio taken directly from the microphone iOS device to the receiver. (in a live way)

I´ve downloaded all the git example projects, and in all of them use a "loadMedia" method to start the casting. Example of one of those:

```
- (NSInteger)loadMedia:(GCKMediaInformation *)mediaInfo
          autoplay:(BOOL)autoplay
      playPosition:(NSTimeInterval)playPosition;
```

Can I follow this approach to do what I want? If so, what´s the expected delay?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Some time ago I implemented a PTT using sockets.

Comment: This is more a question on iOS: give chromecast an audio stream of correct format and it plays that. Bit the key is to provide it with a stream, so you need to work on that part; you need to be able to serve the audio stream (real time) from your phone.

Comment: So you suggest converting the iphone into a streaming audio server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echo is likely if the device (iOS, Android, or Chrome) is in range of the speakers.  That said:

Pick a fast codec that is supported, such as [CELT/Opus](http://www.opus-codec.org/) or [Vorbis](http://www.vorbis.com/)

I haven't tried either of these, but they should be possible.

1. Implement your own protocol using CastChannel that passes the binary data.  You'll want to do some simple conversion of the stream from Binary to something a bit more friendly.  Take a look at [Intro to Web Audio](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/) for using [AudioContext](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/).

or, 2. Setup a trivial server to stream from on your device, then tell the Receiver to just access that local server.